# How does MongoDB WiredTiger store files

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger, lsm-tree

MongoDB WiredTiger offers LSMT for storage. Great, so in memory it maintains a balanced search tree which is flushed to disk depending on configuration (time or size). But q is, how is the data stored on disk? LSMT in Cassandra/HBase are stored as immutable files. These are compacted from time to time. Data is inserted/updated/deleted as cells which are part of a logical distributed dictionary. So each cell is identified by key, column name and version.
But MongoDB uses BSON. This is a single document.so q arises:

1. Does MongoDB break down BSON into cells and updates/versions them? Most unlikely, since BSON was designed for disk storage.
2. In that case, how is the memtable (balanced search tree) update the BSON file? Is the BSON file mutable? LSMT uses immutable files in Cassandra/HBase.
3. In general, how does MongoDB WT do updates? Mutable files on disk, or immutable, and the effort for index management? Since MongoDB offers lots of indexing types.
   Thanks